# basis of the p-adics $\mathbb{Q}_p$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

The p-adics $\mathbb{Q}_p$ are uncountable (because they can be represented by infinite strings of integers in $[0,p-1]$) and hence must be infinite dimensional as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$. What is a concrete example of a basis of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no concrete example for the same reason that there is no concrete example for a Hamel basis for $\Bbb R$ over $\Bbb Q$.

It is consistent with the failure of the axiom of choice that every linear functional from $\Bbb Q_p$ to $\Bbb Q$ is continuous, and therefore is completely decided by values on a countable set (since $\Bbb Q_p$ is separable). There can only be $2^{\aleph_0}$ of these functionals.

But if there is a basis its cardinality must be $2^{\aleph_0}$ and therefore we can generate $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ linear functionals. So in models where the above happens, there is no basis for $\Bbb Q_p$ over $\Bbb Q$. And this means that we can't write an explicit basis, and that we must rely on the axiom of choice for proving it exists.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble parsing your second paragraph. Are you saying that every linear functional form $\mathbb{Q}_p$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ is continuous? What topology are we using for $\mathbb{Q}$ here?

Comment: I believe you, but I don't follow the reasoning of anything you wrote. What is the small argument for how you are concluding $2^{\aleph_0}$ everywhere

Comment: Cardinal arithmetic. It's not hard to show that if $V$ is a vector space of size $2^{\aleph_0}$ over the rationals (like $\Bbb Q_p$) then its basis must have cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$; in the case of the continuous functions as they are fully decided by a countable dense subset we can restrict to functions from that countable subset to the rationals, and there are exactly $2^{\aleph_0}$ of those; and finally for the $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$, if you have a basis, every function from the basis to the field extends to a unique linear functional and there are that many of those.

Comment: When it comes to logic, I’m an outsider looking in, but I find this answer very, very pleasing.

Comment: @user90219: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1267196/cardinality-of-a-basis-of-an-infinite-dimensional-vector-space/1267596#1267596 has the full argument for the least trivial part, the cardinality of the basis.