# Does every map in dual have a predual in infinite-dimensional spaces?

Tags: linear-transformations, dual-spaces

Let $V$ be an infinite-dimensional vector space having a countable basis, let $V'$ be its dual space and let $R: V' \rightarrow V'$ be a linear map. Is it always true that there is a map $T: V \rightarrow V$ such that $R$ is its dual map, i.e. $R = T'$?

So the answer makes sense to be "no". As I do not understand cardinals, it would be great if one can give an explicit counterexample. Any help appreciated!

Comment: I do not even know if the answer is yes or no. I started getting around the definitions (which usually works with duals) but it's too complicated :(

Comment: I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2878483/when-is-exponentiation-of-cardinals-increasing) if someone has a reference for $(1)$.

Comment: I also noticed your comment dissappeared, no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: both $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}<\aleph_1^{\aleph_1}$ and $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1^{\aleph_1}$ are consistent with the ZFC axioms (note that the former is forced by the Continuum Hypothesis). This and the argument below show at the very least that **the answer to your question cannot be a solid yes**. See [Asaf Karagila's answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2878489) for more insight about $(1)$.

---

My goal is to prove that as soon as $V$ is "big enough", this is impossible for cardinality reasons as $|\operatorname{End}V|<|\operatorname{End}V^*|$ (so there can be no surjective map from $\operatorname{End}V$ to  $\operatorname{End}V^*$).

I will need the following result for which I couldn't find a reference but which seems reasonable: $$\text{If $a,b$ are cardinals such that $a<b$, then $a^a<b^b$.}\tag{1}$$

Since an endomorphism is determined by the choice of an element of $V$ for each element of a basis, you have $$|\operatorname{End}V|=|V|^{\dim V}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad|\operatorname{End}V^*|=|V^*|^{\dim V^*}$$

[**Lemma$^{\star}$:** If $|V|>|k|$ where $k$ is the ground field, then $\dim V=|V|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1267196/cardinality-of-a-basis-of-an-infinite-dimensional-vector-space).

Therefore, assuming $|V|>|k|$, you have $$|\operatorname{End}V|<|\operatorname{End}V^*|\Longleftrightarrow |V|^{|V|}<|V^*|^{|V^*|}$$

[**Lemma$^{\star}$:** If $V$ is not finite-dimensional, then $\dim V<\dim V^*$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/35863)

**Corollary (of the two lemmas together):** If $|V|>|k|$, then $|V|<|V^*|$.

**Conclusion (up to $(1)$):**$$|V|>|k|\implies |\operatorname{End}V|<|\operatorname{End}V^*|$$

$^{\star}$(note that this is a link)